# Serial IP modem device with TCP/IP address

Tags: node.js, modbus, modbus-tcp

I need to know I have one serial IP modem device in which I can set my TCP/IP address.

How can I receive data with help of nodejs?

Is it possible with Modbus packages?

Comment: How to receive data from what and to what? The modem works as an TCP server or TCP client? NodeJS can be used as TCP client or server, usign modbus or not.

Comment: Modem as TCP client and nodejs TCP server multiple modem can connect. Mod of communication is modbus

Comment: So the modem is a TCP client but is a TCP server in relation the other modens who will connect. In this case, the first modem is a TCP server and the others are the TCP client. In principle, this approach does not need to use modbus tcp.